# ReactJS - Unclear Behaviour of Array.map and Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While fixing a bug in some old code I came across a cumbersome implementation of an `input`s list, as exemplified in the following minimal example.

When you fill both inputs, the re-order algorithm works well.
However when only one `input` is filled, it just copies the value into the second `input`.
I *think* it has something to do with the `key` property of the `Array.map` function - that are currently set with the indices (which is considered an anti-pattern) - however there are no IDs I can use to map the data in a more meaningful way.

I'm currently putting aside this being a bad implementation, as I want to understand what's going on with these `key`s (or alternatively to find out I'm mistaking and the bug is somewhere else).

```js
class MyTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isAscending: true,
      placeholders: ['first', 'second'],
      values: [1, 2],
      customLabels: {},
    }
  }
  
  reverse() {
    const { values, placeholders, customLabels, isAscending } = this.state;
    
    const sortedData = values.map((value, index) => ({
      value,
      placeholder: placeholders[index],
      customLabel: customLabels[index],
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => (isAscending ? 1 : -1) * (b.value - a.value));

    const newPlaceholders = [];
    const newValues = [];
    const newCustomLabels = {};
    
    sortedData.forEach((dataObject, index) => {
      const { value, placeholder, customLabel } = dataObject;
     
      newPlaceholders.push(placeholder);
      newValues.push(value);
      if (customLabel) newCustomLabels[index] = customLabel;
    });
    
    console.log({ newCustomLabels }); // Here I can verify that `customLabels` is sorted as expected
    
    this.setState({
      isAscending: !isAscending,
      placeholders: newPlaceholders,
      values: newValues,
      customLabels: newCustomLabels,
    });
  }
  
  onChange(e, index) {
    const { customLabels } = this.state;

    const newCustomLabels = Object.assign({}, customLabels);
    newCustomLabels[index] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      customLabels: newCustomLabels,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { placeholders, customLabels, values } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        {
          placeholders.map((placeholder, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={customLabels && customLabels[index]}
                onChange={(e) => this.onChange.bind(this)(e, index)}
              />
              {` with value: ${values[index]}`}
            </div>
          ))
        }
        <button onClick={this.reverse.bind(this)}>Reverse Order</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTest />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Definitely have to put a unique key for each data set. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: @gaditzkhori Can you please explain the unwanted behaviour that is the reason for this best-practice that's explained in the documentation?

Comment: Pretty well explained here: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children. As well as Dan Abramov codepen examples including reordering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on the comments, you can create a unique key in each render, that works, but you are making a mistake about controlled/uncontrolled input, probably you are seeing on the logs a warning telling you that. That means that the input field value must never be `undefined` (controlled, must set an onChange event callback) or be the default behavior, you cannot mix them. This render function will fix your bug:

```
render() {
    const { placeholders, customLabels = {}, values } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {placeholders.map((placeholder, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              placeholder={placeholder}
              value={customLabels[index] || ''}
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e, index)}
            />
            {` with value: ${values[index]}`}
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.reverse.bind(this)}>Reverse Order</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Edit**: 
sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-payne-xpern?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Not sure I understand what you were saying about controlled/uncontrolled input, would love to hear more! And your sandbox doesn't work :(

Comment: Really sry about that... I forgot to save the file before sharing it... I updated the link. And about controlled/uncontrolled input, this link is really helpful https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Comment: But the snippet I posted with the render function is correct

Comment: That's interesting, I was completely sure it's something with the keys, because changing them caused different behaviors. Thanks a lot for the info!